# How to REGEX this text

Tags: android, regex

I need a regex for this rule:

1. Positions 1 – 10 are numeric and is the company’s NEQ (Quebec Enterprise Number:that mean it starts with 11 or 22 or 33)
2. Positions 11 and 12 are TQ
3. Positions 13 – 16 are numeric

Example:

```
1134567890 TQ 0001
```

Could you please help me.
Thank

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Help you with what? You just told us what you need to do, but what have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter? You cannot just post a problem on Stack Overflow and expect others to solve it for you.

Comment: See http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex which satisfies all the mentioned conditions,

```
^(?:11|22|33)[0-9]{8} TQ [0-9]{4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cY1jR5/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should be OK

```
^((11)|(22)|(33))[0-9]{8}\s(TQ)\s[0-9]{4}$
```